# shouldShowMenuForRowAt not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, menu

First time trying to implement a menu. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` used in `UITableView` in a `UITableViewController.` TableView is configured as follows:

```
fileprivate configureTableView() {
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TransactionTableViewCell.nibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TransactionTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = TransactionEntryTableViewCell.defaultHeight
}
```

I create the cell below like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TransactionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TransactionTableViewCell else { DLog("ERROR getting TransactionTableViewCell"); return UITableViewCell() }
        let entry = entries[indexPath.row]
        cell.entry = entry
        return cell

    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newTransactionCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Strings.AddANewTransaction
        return cell

    default:
        assert(false)
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Menu related methods are as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    print("shouldShowMenuForRowAt")
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("canPerformAction")
    return action == MenuAction.duplicate.selector()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    print("action = \(action)")
}
```

All seems to be working fine; however, the method `shouldShowMenuForRowAt` is not being called when long pressed on the table.

I have a sample project that works fine. However, this is not working. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `UITableViewDelegate` method instead of `NSObject`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return action == MenuAction.duplicate.selector()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you implemented

`override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

Not the actual required method:

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

You are welcome, I wasted an hour with this exact same issue!